# Angular Wait an Observable to finish before starting other Observable

Tags: angular, observable

I have two Observables :

```
constructor(
    private afAuth:AngularFireAuth,
    private db:AngularFireDatabase
    ) {
      
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(x=> 
      {
        this.userId=x?.uid;
        console.log(this.userId);
      });
      
      console.log(this.userId);
      this.db.list('users/'+this.userId+'/movies-favourited').valueChanges().subscribe(data=>{
        this.favouriteList=data;
      });
   }
```

How do I make sure that I get the userId in the first Observable before getting the list in second Observable.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either replace the first observable with promise

OR

You can put the second observable inside the first one like this:

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(x=> 
  {
    this.userId=x?.uid;
    console.log(this.userId);
  this.db.list('users/'+this.userId+'/movies-favourited').valueChanges().subscribe(data=>{
    this.favouriteList=data;
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do it is by using `switchMap` as shown below:

```
this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    switchMap(user => {
        if(user) {
            this.userId = user.uid;
            this.db.list('users/'+this.userId+'/movies-favourited')
                .valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
                    this.favouriteList = data;
                });
        }
    })
);
```

You can read more about `switchMap` [**here**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap).

Comment: Also you can use the rxjs concat operator, https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat

Answer (score 0):

Once the first observable successfully retrieve data by subscribing it will subscribe to the second observable which will solve your problem.

```
constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase
) {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(x => {
        this.userId = x?.uid;
        console.log(this.userId);
        this.db.list('users/' + this.userId + '/movies-favourited').valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
            this.favouriteList = data;
        });
        console.log(this.userId);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why and what are the better approaches ?

Comment: The inner sub stays alive and can fire unexpectedly (everytime the outer fires, you create a new a new inner subscription). This approach will really bite you in more complex scenarios. You really want to ‘connect’ the observables using proper rxjs operators like a switchmap so you only end up with a single subscription. Killing the outer one will then also kill the ‘inner’ one.

Answer (score 0):

This must be the solution for you task.

```
this.afAuth.authState
                .subscribe(
                    (x: any) => {
                        this.userId = x?.uid;
                        if (x.uid) {
                            this.db.list('users/' + this.userId + '/movies-favourited').valueChanges()
                                .subscribe(
                                    (data: any) => {
                                        this.favouriteList = data;
                                    },
                                    (error) => {
                                        console.log(error);
                                    });
                        }
    
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                );
```

More suggestions to optimize your code:

1. Consider put your code inside ngOnInit() lifecycle instead of constuctor.
2. Define data types of your variables 'x' and 'data'.
3. Don't forget to unsubscribe.
4. Handle your errors in some way.